# logical mvc place to place code snippet

Tags: jquery, cakephp

Ok, so I don't even know if i'm following proper MVC patters for this, but I have 2 elements for my default page that i broke out into 2 separate element files, my top navbar, and a login window. I did this to help maintaining and upgrading these elements easier. Each file contains the html, css, and javascript necessary for that element to look and work right.

The problem arises, however, when they become interdependent. For example, the navbar has this snippet in it's script tags:

```
$('#login-register-link').on('click', LoginWindow.show);
```

but `LoginWindow.show` is defined in the LoginWindow element, which is outputted after the navbar, causing an undefined error.

How can I solve this logically? I mean I know I could place this line in the loginwindow element, but that's not correct programming as loginwindow shouldn't know anything about what is using it. Any tips on correct way to break these elements out and how to solve the dependency issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't output inline script-blocks throughout your page

First of all, don't output inline JavaScripts. Collect your scripts and output them at the end of your page.

CakePHP offers the option to 'buffer' scripts and output them in one go via the JsHelper;

```
// Append the script to the JS-buffer
$this->Js->buffer('$("#login-register-link").on("click", LoginWindow.show);');

// At the end of your layout, output all collected scripts;
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

Which outputs;

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#login-register-link").on("click", LoginWindow.show);
    }
</script>
```

### Don't rely on an 'ID' if not necessary, use event-delegation

You're being very specific as to *which* link should be used in order to open the login-window. What (for example) if I want to add a second link? (e.g. Welcome! To register for this site, visit 'this' link.)

In most cases it's better to reduce the amount of IDs in your HTML and don't rely on them, unless strictly necessary. It's *true* that an 'ID'-selector in JavaScript is faster than other selectors, but the differences are neglectable, unless your page is *very* large.

#### Event delegation (bubbling)

Additionally, make use of event-delegation ('bubbling'); doing so reduces the amount of event-listeners attached to your site (which is faster, less memory-hungry) and *also* allows you to set a *single* listener that works *even for dynamically added content*.

For your example, output the JavaScript in the 'LoginWindow' element and make the loginwindow 'available' to other elements by sending a 'click' event. But *only* if those elements have a 
'target-login-window' class;

```
//The links
<a href='/register' class='some classes and target-login-window'>Register here!</a>
<a href='/register' class='target-login-window'>Or use this link!</a>

//The script
//Note that the listener is attached to the <body> of your HTML
//but will only respond to clicks on an element that has a 'target-login-window'
//class.

//I picked the body here, but it's best practice to pick a 'wrapper' element
//on your page (e.g. an element that contains the relevant content)

$('body').on('click', '.target-login-window', LoginWindow.show);
```

Alternatively, use HTML5 'data' attributes to specify the intent of a link;

```
//The links
<a href='/register' data-target="login-window">Register here!</a>
<a href='/register' data-target="login-window">Or use this link!</a>

//The script
$('body').on('click', '[data-target="login-window"]', LoginWindow.show);
```

### Some additional thoughts

Initializing the listeners can also be moved to your 'LoginWindow' JavaScript class. That will make it easier to maintain and removes that code from your page, for example;

```
LoginWindow.init = function (options) {
    // other initialization stuff
    // ....

    this.initListeners();
};

loginWindow.initListeners = function() {
    $('body').on('click', '[data-target="login-window"]', this.show); 
};
```

And on your page;

```
$this->Js->buffer('LoginWindow.init();');
```

Some people may offer that even this part of the code (`LoginWindow.init();`) should be moved to an external .js file.

Personally, I'm not always fond of that approach; IMO external JavaScript files should, in most cases, be 'passive' until they are *actively* initialized from the page.

In my opinion, the page *itself* should always be in control (for example; a javascript should not locate all h3-headers on my page and start to style them, *unless* told to do so), but again, this is just a matter of opinion :)

Comment: I wish i could upvote a million times. Thank you for the VERY helpful detaled information, and for going the extra mile on proper usage with id's. I can't tell you how much that helps, as that was something i never thought was good practice. And as soon as I read the buffer line, i immediately remembered that feature. Thanks again!

Comment: @LordZardeck I'm glad I was able to assist. These kind of things are always 'tricky'; To further improve this code, I'd suggest to move creating the listeners to the LoginWindow object as well and only *initialize* it inside the page. (Personally, I *dislike* external JavaScripts that automatically run/initialize code without being explicitly called from the page). I'll add that to my answer

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to register event handlers once your document is ready which occurs after all markup has been loaded and any linked resources have been acquired. For example with jQuery you would do the following:

```
$(function(){
    $('#login-register-link').on('click', LoginWindow.show);
});
```

That way, you can ensure that `LoginWindow` has been added to the global namespace regardless of whether it was declared before or after your event handler.

If I were you, I would probably look at a JavaScript MVC framework like [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) because they have some good UI signalling patterns that would probably help you. I went through something similar phase to you where you realize that CakePHP conventions don't support JavaScript development very well.

Comment: i should have mentioned that i already had wrapped that in a onload function